Make every element of the List Of Figures (LOF) the same size
I am writing a report and for formatting reasons I will need to have different sizes for the captions of my figures.
For example, here we can see that 2.3 is smaller than the other, I would like them all at the same size on the TOF but while keeping their respective size.
Here is how I did figure 2.3 if that matter.
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{Images2A/Part2/solar_fuel_dep.png}
      \caption{\footnotesize Organizational chart of the Solar Fuels department \cite{Website}}
\end{wrapfigure}



never put formatting in the argument of \caption \section etc, instead define them to use a suitable font. That said, if you ignore this advice, \caption[normal text in lof]{\footnotesize small text in body of document}

I would recommend to use package caption to be able to configure the font (size, variant etc.) of the captions — not only the general font in the document preamble, but also per figure and even per caption. See the package manual for more information. So the size of the caption in the LoF would not be affected. But without a minimal working example this is only a guess. Depending on the class there could be other solutions.
